# Did I write this recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a recursive method to reverse a list, using no loops and no built-in functions such as **reverse, reversed**, or **::** (the list-slicing operator).

Did I do this properly?

```
def reverseList(alist):
    if len(alist) == 1:
        return alist
    else:
        return reverseList(alist[1:]) + [alist[0]]

print (reverseList([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please. Also, what is currently happening in your code that is not working as you expect?

Comment: well I'm able to reverse the list. Im just learning recursion and I wanted to know if wrote this correctly with no loops or built in functions.

Comment: Your code breaks if you put in an empty list. What do you think the change in your code should be to handle that case?

Comment: @PrestonM This is not something we should suggest to be sent to Code-Review. We should get out of the habit of sending question-askers over there. Please read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) meta post for clarification.

Comment: If you want an additional challenge, try rewriting so that it swaps the first and last elements before recursing.

Comment: @idjaw shouldn't we? Presented code works as intended (at least outside of corner cases, but that's not unheard of when code goes to CR), question is fairly open... For me, it smells a lot like Code Review candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did great.  The code is short, clear, readable, and calls itself appropriately.  Yes, you can recode this for the empty list.

```
if len(alist) <= 1:
    return alist
```

Also, try a few more test cases:

```
print (reverseList([1,2,3,4,5]))
print (reverseList([1, [False, 2.71828], ["hello", "world", "I'm", "done"], 4, 5]))
print (reverseList([])
print (reverseList([7])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works, except for the empty list []. You should add it as a base case. For example a correct code would look like:

```
def reverseList(alist):
    if len(alist) <= 1:
        return alist
    else:
        return reverseList(alist[1:]) + [alist[0]]

print (reverseList([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: `if (len(alist) <= 1)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13802519)

Comment: @Andreas this does provide an answer. Did you mean it should have some example code?

Comment: As it is written now, it's more like a comment. Provide some explanation or some background information to make it an answer

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.